# Что такое executor в aiogram?

Tags: python, aiogram

Всем привет, почему в доке нету объяснение. Что такое executor в aiogram ? Так вот помогите разобраться что это или статью скиньте

Answer (score 1):

Если вкраце то это модуль aiogram'a который позволяет тебе запустить бота либо на вебхуках либо в полинге.

[Документация](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/utils/executor.html)

[Исходник екзекутера](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/_modules/aiogram/utils/executor.html)